# Performance of placing the value of an object field in a variable

Tags: c++, class, object, field

Here are two code snippet in c++:

```
some_previously_defined_array_object_class object1;

int nrows = object1.rows;
int ncols = object1.cols;
int objectsize = object1.size();

int some_metric1;
int some_metirc2;

some_metric1 = nrows*ncols+2/(3+ncols);
some_metric2 = objectsize+0.5*ncols;
// Other computations involving the previous int
```

Instead of defining some int containing the value of the fields of my object, should I simply always use object1.rows directly (and the others too?)

Beside the fact I think that it is easier to change the value of the ints at one place, at first I thought that it would be more efficient to place the values in ints instead of accessing the field every time. Now, I am quite unsure that it is the case for roes and cols.

On the other hand, for "object.size()", since it is a function and that the value is not likely to change often, is it a safe bet to compute it once and using the int for the rest of the program instead of computing every time? Ok, in this case I could have created a field "size = rows*cols" in my class, but this is only a simple example.

So, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `object1` is a local variable, there is already space on the stack reserved for `object1.rows` and `object1.cols`; creating more variables on the stack to hold the same value provides no performance benefit, and may indeed cause a performance *penalty* depending on the circumstances.

In either case, the performance difference is going to be negligible.  However, I would avoid creating extra local variables simply as a matter of cleanliness and style.

In the `object1.size()` case you may see a performance gain if you use the value of `objectsize` more than once.  If you are only running these computations a few times then, again, the performance difference will be negligible. (If the compiler can see the implementation of `size()` and it is declared `const` then it may well be able to optimize away multiple calls to `size()` anyway!)

Comment: OK from what I understand from both answers, performance should not be a real issue on normal circumstance. I will consider that it is more a coding style preference. Right now I am not doing over the top stuff but it will soon change so I guess I'll have to take the type of operations I am doing into account each time.

Comment: @Doombot That is correct. Unless this code is performance-critical and being run repeatedly, you would be lucky to notice even a 1 nanosecond difference in execution time between all of the stylistic options you have presented.

Comment: @Doombot I should add that generally you should write code for *humans*, not the computer. The source code is what your coworkers will be reading and maintaining. Premature optimization is a bad thing; if it turns out that something is a bottleneck then you can come back to it *after* you profile the program. (1) Make it work (2) Make it work right (3) Make it work fast

Answer (score 0):

It is best to do it the way you show, using temporary variables to improve readability and ease typing. This is a very common situation and the compiler will optimize it for you.

Comment: Ah compiler optimization... Forgot about it! Thanks!